# Ajax is calling ASP.NET MVC Controller Action Twice, but Only on First Ajax Call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I'm using ASP.NET, and I'm using Ajax to make a request to a controller action. This action increases one of the values on the page in the database by the value entered. It's working fine, but, for some reason, the first time that I attempt to update this value, the controller action executes twice, causing the value to increase by two times the value I entered. Ajax success is only being called once. When I try to update this value again, it only executes once. I've tried just about every solution I've found online, and none of them have worked.

Here is the .cshtml code. The value of the "AmountToAdd" number input is added to the TotalValue and RemainingAmount. Ajax is being called inside the $('#addToPOButton).on('click') function call.

```
@*Customer/PurchaseOrderDetails*@

@using TQS_Purchase_Order_Tracker.Models
@model Tuple<PurchaseOrderModel, CompanyModel, List<InvoiceModel>, List<InvoiceLineItemModel>>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PurchaseOrderDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" />

<main>
    @{
        PurchaseOrderModel po = Model.Item1;
        CompanyModel company = Model.Item2;
        List<InvoiceModel> invoices = Model.Item3;
        List<InvoiceLineItemModel> invoiceLineItems = Model.Item4;
    }

    <span id="back-to-po-list-icon" class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-3x" style="float: left" title="Back to PO List"></span>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <table class="descr-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Total Value</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@string.Format("${0:n} {1}", po.TotalValue, po.Currency)</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <table class="descr-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Remaining Amount</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@string.Format("${0:n} {1}", po.ValueRemaining, po.Currency)</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <div id="amountToAddWrapper" class="hidden">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h3 class="text-center">Add Value to Purchase Order</h3>
                <table class="descr-table" style="width: 50%;">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Amount to Add</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="number" id="amountToAdd" class="form-control" min="0.00" step="0.01" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <button type="button" id="addToPOButton" class="btn btn-success">Add to PO</button>
                <button type="button" id="cancelAddToPOButton" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <hr />
    </div>
</main>

<script type="text/javascript" src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js")></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js")></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src=@Url.Content("~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.responsive.min.js")></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Custom/formatting.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function () {
        
        //Handle click of add to PO button.
        $('#addToPOButton').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            if ($('#amountToAdd').val() !== '') {
                appendZeroesToCurrency('#amountToAdd');
                
                if ($('#amountToAdd').val() !== '0.00') {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("AddToPO", "Customer")?' + $.param({ 'purchaseOrderID': '@po.PurchaseOrderID' }),
                        type: 'PUT',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        async: false,
                        data: JSON.stringify({ AmountToAdd: $('#amountToAdd').val() })
                    }).done(function () {
                        hideAmountToAddArea();
                        location.reload(true);
                    }).fail(function (data) {
                        alert(data.responseJSON.message);
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        //Handle click of cancel add to PO button.
        $('#cancelAddToPOButton').on('click', function () {
            hideAmountToAddArea();
        });
    });

    function showAmountToAddArea() {
        $('#amountToAddWrapper').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#addPOFunds').addClass('hidden');
        $('#amountToAddWrapper').ready(function () {
            let offset = 95;
            let el = document.querySelector('#amountToAddWrapper');
            window.scroll({ top: (el.offsetTop - offset), left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
        });
    }

    function hideAmountToAddArea() {
        $('#amountToAdd').val('');
        $('#amountToAddWrapper').addClass('hidden');
        $('#addPOFunds').removeClass('hidden');
    }
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is the controller action.

```
        [HttpPut]
        [Route("Customer/AddToPO/{purchaseOrderID:string}")]
        public ActionResult AddToPO(string purchaseOrderID)
        {
            //Get JSON from body.
            Stream req = Request.InputStream;
            req.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string jsonString = new StreamReader(req).ReadToEnd();
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

            decimal? amountToAdd = (decimal?)json["AmountToAdd"];

            if(PODataAccess.IncreasePOValue(purchaseOrderID, amountToAdd))
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 204;
                return Json(new { message = string.Format("The value of PO {0} has been successfully increased.", purchaseOrderID) });
            }
            else
            {
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
                return Json(new { message = string.Format("An error has occurred while attempting to increase the value of PO {0}.", purchaseOrderID) });
            }
        }
```

Comment: You've got a lot of code here. I suspect that some of this isn't necessary to reproduce the issue you're experiencing. Can you look over [mcve] and follow the guidelines there to remove anything that isn't necessary to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I test your code and first time it will call controller once.Maybe somewhere you call the controller with form or another ajax?